# How should my config look for an influxdb running on a IoT device?

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to run a single node instance of influxdb on a IoT gateway to collect time series sensor data. Currently I'm having trouble to understand what a good config would look like to match my hardware as well as the available storage.

The hardware specs are the following:

- ARM Cortex A5 (400 MHz)
- 128 MB RAM
- around 50 MB of available storage

What is concerning the writes and reads on the database we estimate a maximum of 3 (very likely much less) writes per second, maybe up to 250-350 unique series of data and only occasional queries from some client.

Can anybody give me some advises how to set up the config? All I can find on the influxdata homepage seem to only fit a much stronger hardware as well as a much more demanding use case what's concerning system load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that spec will stand up to the requirements.

I'm running it on a Raspberry Pi2 which has significantly more resource and it is OK but I still limit the amount of data going through.

You will certainly need to set up suitable retention policies and matching continuous queries to cut down the data.

I have 2 main datasets. The environmental monitoring has 11 locations (each location being a multi-sensor platform) and 9 sensor types and takes a reading around every 40-50s (actually some are less as they come from external weather API's). So perhaps an average of 2 records per second though by no means evenly spaced. The data is picked up from an MQTT broker and sent to InfluxDB via Node-Red.

The other is for system monitoring. That has significantly more data coming in (from Telegraf) but still restricted to 30s (+/-5s) collection intervals.

For the environmental data, I keep 24h of the details with an hourly summary then kept for 3 years.

Currently, InfluxDB is showing around 10-30% CPU (mainly 8-10 with peaks every 30s or so unsurprisingly) and around 24% of the 1GB memory.

Total size of data is currently 417Mb

Incidentally, the Pi is running Node-Red (a node.js application), mosquitto (MQTT broker), InfluxDB, Telegraf, Grafana and 3 serial port devices. It isn't running a GUI desktop. It copes OK but will occasionally go slow.

Given the low cost and high reliability of something like a Raspberry Pi, I would advise putting something like this in place instead of your current selection.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!
Meanwhile i collected some amount of data, and it would be interesting to see how big the actually stored data is, where can I find this information?

Comment: Hi @p0fi, sorry about the delay. If you look in your config file, you will see the data folder.

Comment: Yep, there is the path to the data folder, but also some wal and shard paths. I'm confused, what of all that is my actual data? And inside the data folder there are a couple of other folders, I don't seem to understand how the actual data is stored. Could you give me a hint how so see how much storage my actual data points take?

Comment: Not sure about the wal ones but the shards are the main data. InfluxDB splits its data into shards to keep the individual file sizes manageable. I would guess that you need to measure the whole folder.